# Write http request on a file with nodejs

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, fs

how can I save http request on a file?
Im using nodejs as a server. I send data via ajax as it shows below

```
user_info = 
    {
        system_info: [
            {'browesr': browser},
            {'brower-version': version},
            {'cookies': cookieEnabled},
            {'os': os},
            {'os-version': osVersion}
        ]
    }
}

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:4560',
    data: {"info" : JSON.stringify(user_info)},
    type: 'POST',
    jsonCallback: 'callback',
    success: function(data) {
        var ret = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        $('#lblResponse').html(ret.msg);
        console.log('success');
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log('Error:' + error.message);
        $('#lblResponse').html('Error connecting to the server.');
    }
});
```

the post method works correctly and in server side the data is receive too.
my problem is how to save data!
I search and I find something about streaming. this is my nodejs server code.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    console.log('Request Received');

    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Context-Type': 'text/plain',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    });

    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        var rstream = fs.createReadStream(JSON.parse(chund));
        var wstream = fs.createWriteStream('info.txt');
        rstream.pipe(wstream);
        str += chunk;
        console.log('GOT DATA');
    });

    res.end('{"msg": "OK"}');
}).listen(4560, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:4560/');
```

I use fs module and streaming, but didnt work at all, "info.txt" is near server code in the same directory.

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're most of the way there. Here's a working example based on your code:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    console.log('Request Received');

    var body = '';

    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Context-Type': 'text/plain',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    });

    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        body += chunk;
    });

    req.on('end', function() {
        fs.writeFile('file.json', body, 'utf8');
        res.end('{"msg": "OK"}');
    })

}).listen(4560, '127.0.0.1'); console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:4560/');
```

This will save the content that you send it to a file called 'file.json'.

You also need to make a couple of minor changes to your Ajax request:

```
url: 'http://127.0.0.1:4560',
data: JSON.stringify({"info" : user_info}),
contentType: "application/json",
type: 'POST',
jsonCallback: 'callback',
```

If you want to modify what you're writing to the file, then you could so something like:

```
req.on('end', function() {
    var parsedJson = JSON.parse(body);
    fs.writeFile('file.json', JSON.stringify(parsedJson.info), 'utf8');
    res.end('{"msg": "OK"}');
})
```

If you want to append the file, rather than overwriting it then you could do something like:

```
req.on('end', function() {
    var parsedJson = JSON.parse(body);
    // Read and parse the JSON file
    var file = require('file.json');
    file[parsedJson.someKindOfID] = parsedJson;
    fs.writeFile('file.json', JSON.stringify(file), 'utf8');
    res.end('{"msg": "OK"}');
})
```

But this depends on your data structure in the file.

Comment: Thanks buddy! Just one problem, when I open file.json, the data saved like this: info=%7B%22system_info%22%3A%5B%7B%22browser...., why didnt show the data like normal json?

Comment: On your Ajax request, try `data: JSON.stringify({"info" : user_info})` and set `contentType: "application/json"`

Comment: Correct! , but one more problem, when you open page in new operating system or web browser, the server delete previous json and write the new, how can i append the data?

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example of that. Alternatively, you could just create a new file for each request and change the file name.